# Integration of trigonometric functions times a simple rational function using residues

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

In the course of my research I have found a few integrals that I would like to have closed-form answers to:

$$\int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{8 \pi^4 \cot{ \big( \frac{\pi}{6} z \big)}}{\sqrt{3} (\cosh{2 \pi a} - \cos{2 \pi z})} \ dz $$ and

$$\int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{16 \pi^4}{\big(1+2 \cos{ \big(\frac{\pi}{3} z\big)} \big) (\cosh{2 \pi a} - \cos{2 \pi z})} \ dz $$

I am concerned with the answer when $1 > Re(c) >0$ and $a > 0$ is a known numerical constant.

In both cases, the rational function ruins the periodicity, but its still simple enough that it seems like there might be a way to compute these if you pick the correct contour. Sadly, neither function decays fast enough along the real line to be able to close the contour with a semi-circle. Thanks to the exponential decay away form the real axis, I have been trying to work with box contours and find 2 verticals lines with a known relationship between the integrals along those lines (eg they're equal up to some known factor) but now I've run out of good ideas.

I also need to compute a similar integral that contains only trig functions:

$$\int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \frac{2 \pi^4 \sec{ \big( \frac{\pi}{2} z \big)}  \cos{ \big( \frac{\pi}{6} z \big)}}{-\cosh{2 \pi a} + \cos{2 \pi z}} \ dz $$

with the same restrictions. It has a period of 12 but I can't figure out how to use this to compute the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after asking this question I had a new idea; multiply by a 'convergence factor' inside the integral that reduces the contribution from the semi-circular arc. Sum the residues and calculate the value of this new integral, then take the limit that the convergence factor approaches $1$, yielding the original integral.

In this case, $$\lim_{b->0} \int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \frac{e^{-b z}}{z-1} \frac{8 \pi^4 \cot{ \big( \frac{\pi}{6} z \big)}}{\sqrt{3} (\cosh{2 \pi a} - \cos{2 \pi z})} \ dz $$
can be computed. The sum of the residues appears to be logarithmically divergent, but these divergences cancel when all of the residues are included. The answer is somewhat messy so I won't post it until I have simplified it further, but this is the main idea. It should work for all 3 integrals.